# Substring with string, returning values between two words in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, substring

I am getting from a Telnet buffer a string like the following:

```
"<CONNECTED><SENDING_VIDEO_LIST><START_VIDEO_LIST>test.mp4|test_3.mp4|test_2.mp4|<END_VIDEO_LIST><PLAYING_test.mp4_STARTED>"
```

I want to select everything between the two indicators `<START_VIDEO_LIST>` and `<END_VIDEO_LIST>` which is in this case euqal to:

`test.mp4|test_3.mp4|test_2.mp4|`

Is there an efficient way without manipulating the whole string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if you want, you can use a `regex`:

```
<START_VIDEO_LIST>([^<]*)<END_VIDEO_LIST>
```

and the first captured group (`\1`) is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Without regex (can be a less eficient) you can use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.IndexOf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "<CONNECTED><SENDING_VIDEO_LIST><START_VIDEO_LIST>test.mp4|test_3.mp4|test_2.mp4|<END_VIDEO_LIST><PLAYING_test.mp4_STARTED>";
string start = "<START_VIDEO_LIST>";
string end = "<END_VIDEO_LIST>";
int i1 = s.IndexOf(start);
int i2 = s.IndexOf(end);
string result = s.Substring(i1 + start.Length, i2 - i1 - start.Length);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output will be;

```
test.mp4|test_3.mp4|test_2.mp4|
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/yan91C)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex option:

```
string GetContents(string full, string start, string end)
{
    int s = full.IndexOf(start) + start.Length;
    int e = full.IndexOf(end);
    int length = e - s;

    //validate the index and length to ensure Substring wont throw an error (unless you want that of course)
    if (s < 0 || length > full.Length - s)
            return null;

    return full.Substring(s, length);
}
```

which you can call like so:

```
string result = GetContents(input, "<START_VIDEO_LIST>", "<END_VIDEO_LIST>");
```

NOTE: It would be wise to valid your input!